# How to differ between rollup-summary and formula fields using APEX Schema functions?

Tags: apex, formula, roll-up-summary, schema, describefieldresult

I'm using describe functions to retrieve a [DescribeFieldResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm). Now on an Object I have two fields: one is a formula and the other is a rollup-summary. How can I differentiate between these two "types"?

I found already, that both have isCalulate=true but that is not enough to tell them apart.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can tell because when you describe a `Rollup Summary Field`, its describe returns null when you call `getCalculatedFormula()`, unlike a `Formula Field`.

```
system.assertEquals(null, rollupDescribe.getCalculatedFormula());
system.assertNotEquals(null, formulaDescribe.getCalculatedFormula());
```

Comment: Theorycrafting. Heh, I like that.

Comment: Thanks guys, that works perfectly. Might there be a way to find out about what is being rolled-up, like which field on which child object?

Comment: @UweHeim Pretty sure you're SOL there unless you want to break out one of the APIs. Even then I'm not sure what you would actually retrieve.